# Can we get ios device UDID?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am currently making a device where I have to distribute through ad hoc distribution, and I have to register their device UDID. I have a way for them to get their UDID, which is through websitecall [showmyudid](https://showmyudid.com/). The thing is that website for some people, including me actually, looks suspicious, and even if it is not, it is not professional to use the website because this application is for the higher ups and I don't want them to, even by a small chance, have information leakage.
So I was thinking of making my own website using Flutter to get iOS Device UDID. The question is, is that even possible? Using flutter to create webpage that shows iOS Device UDID. Or is there any other way to get the UDID without using external website that is not provided by apple itself, like iTunes back then.

Comment: I would suggest you look for alternatives to adhoc distribution. You could use TestFlight or custom app distribution or unlisted app distribution.

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah I used adhoc distribution with custom webpage for installation, the problem is that getting UDID is currently in my knowledge, kind of impossible without using websites like shown above or diawi and such. If possible I want to get the UDID through something safer like iTunes or from settings and such.

Comment: You can plug the phone into a Mac and then in Finder click on the phone and the click on the text below the device name that shows the model, storage and battery - It will change to show the UDID.